# AWS QuickSight - List all users belonging to a Dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I want to generate a list of all the users that I've shared a specific dashboard with, ideally in a text/csv file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/qs-api-overview.html) (version 2) installed then this is as easy as calling the [`describe-dashboard-permissions`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/quicksight/describe-dashboard-permissions.html) API endpoint. You will have to get the dashboard id first by calling `list-dashboards`.

Otherwise you are stuck with the table provided in the UI under the Share menu button which also lists all permitted users but has no option to export to text (or anything else).